# Use a function to define an optional parameter

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

Is it possible to use the return value of a function instead of a specific value as optional parameter in a function?
For example instead of:

```
public void ExampleMethod(int a, int b, int c=10)
{
}
```

I want something like

```
private int ChangeC(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

public void ExampleMethod(int a, int b, int c=ChangeC(a,b))
{
}
```

Comment: No, because the parameters for that method do not exist in that context. You could just use it on the first line of your method: c = c ?? ChangeC(a,b)

Comment: Please give an example in pseudo code. It is a bit unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: You could have two overloads of the method - one with three parameters & one with two that calls the first using the results of the function call as the third parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the ways:

```
private int ChangeC(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b; 
} 

public void ExampleMethod(int a, int b, int? c=null)
{
    c = c ?? ChangeC(a,b);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

No this is not possible. For a parameter to be optional the value must be a compile time constant. You can however overload the method like so:

```cs
private int ChangeC(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

public void ExampleMethod(int a, int b, int c) {}

public void ExampleMethod(int a, int b)
{
    ExampleMethod(a, b, ChangeC(a, b));
}
```

This way you don't have to deal with nullable value types

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to use the return value of a function instead of a specific value as optional parameter in a function?

No. It is not possible. The C# programming guide on [Optional Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments) says:

> A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> - a constant expression;
> - an expression of the form `new ValType()`, where `ValType` is a value type, such as an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) or a [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs);
> - an expression of the form [`default(ValType)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default), where `ValType` is a value type.

See other answers for alternative solutions.